# rich:fileUpload not working without flash

Tags: java, jsf, upload, richfaces

I am using `rich:fileUpload` for uploading multiple files. It works just fine when I have `allowFlash="true"` but, when I set `allowFlash="false"` it doesn't work anymore. It just doesn't do anything.

Could someone please help me understand why this doesn't work.

Comment: It would be good if you post the error StackTrace

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem. There was an error in the server.log:

`org.richfaces.exception.FileUploadException: Exception parsing multipart request: Request prolog cannot be read`

The problem has something to do with Glassfish 3.1.2 (see [the bug report](https://community.jboss.org/message/724422)).
The solution is to download [web-core.jar](http://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-18444) from the top of the site and overwrite the old file in glassfish.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem, simply add the following to your `components.xml` to disable the Seam multipart filter and the `rich:fileUpload` will work. Not sure if this will break any other Seam features.

```
web:multipart-filter disabled="true"
```

Comment: For Glassfish where does this line go as there is no components.xml?